# How to restore specific datebase from total SQL backup?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, backup

I'm moving a website and I backed up all of my databases from the old host into one total sql backup file.

I need to restore a specific database inside this file to my new host that is used for the wordpress site.

How would I achieve this?

cheers

Comment: How did you do the backup? What is the extension of the file? Is it a zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Open SQL File using a Text editor then search for the specific database, in my case there was a comment declaring where it began. Then copy all the tables into a seperate file with extension .sql